# Can't bind to a member of a Model from a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

MyProduct is the model that has HasError boolean property (with OnPropertyChanged ...) that can change.
MyProductDialogViewModel is:

```
class ProductDialogViewModel : Notifier
{
    public ProductDialogViewModel() { }        
    public MyProduct Product { get; set; }               
    public bool HasError
    {
        get { return Product.HasError; }
    }
}
```

I have assigned MyProductDialogViewModel instance to BaseContentControl.DataContext to inflate a ContentControl.
This View can be inflated with different ViewModels all having HasError property using template binding.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="BaseContentControl" Content="{Binding}" ... >
```

Then I try to extract informations directly from its DataContext.
This don't work:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=BaseContentControl, Path=DataContext.HasError}"/>
```

But this works perfectly.

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=BaseContentControl, Path=DataContext.Product.HasError}"/>
```

I tought it ca be a notifiy problem in the ViewModel so I have changed to this:

```
class ProductDialogViewModel : Notifier
{
    public ProductDialogViewModel() { }

    public MyProduct Product { get; set; }        

    public bool HasError
    {
        get { return Product.HasError; }
        set
        {
            if (Product.HasError != value)
            {
                Product.HasError = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("HasError");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but to no avail (in fact the set method is never called so it never notifies).

I don't want to directly refer to the specific Model instance cause the View can be inflated with different ViewModels.
How can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Does Prouduct class implements INotifypropertychanged and HasError calls OnPropertyChanged event ?

Comment: Yes, it does implements INotifypropertychanged and calls OnPropertyChanged("HasError")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to propagate the `PropertyChanged` event of `MyProduct`, i.e. subscribe to it and invoke `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasError))` if `HasError` property of `MyProduct` being changed:

```
public class ProductDialogViewModel : Notifier
{
    public ProductDialogViewModel() { }

    private MyProduct _product = null;
    public MyProduct Product
    {
        get { return _product; }
        set
        {
            if (_product!=null)
            {
                _product.PropertyChanged -= Product_PropertyChanged;
            }
            _product = value;
            if (_product != null)
            {
                _product.PropertyChanged += Product_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Product_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName==nameof(MyProduct.HasError))
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasError));
        }
    }

    public bool HasError => Product.HasError;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. You should change Product_PropertyChanged in code to ViewModel_PropertyChanged

Comment: @Beorne Done.. :)